# what major functions or standards will be removed( not deprecated) in near future from PHP versions

Tags: php, version, deprecated

This question need to be asked in php lists though but mentioning here if anyone already have links about them.

For example

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference
```

For production server these error are said to be kept disabled upto latest php version. but in how many version they should be converted into fatal errors or warnings?

```
ereg,eregi : and other POSIX Regex
```

These functions  deprecated from PHP 5.3.0 . when this extension is expected to be removed altogether.

These questions are important for all legacy code sites.

Comment: I don't see how this information is relevant. If a feature is deprecated, don't use it for new code. Update any old code you have before updating PHP to a version that removes this feature.

Comment: You know the SO rules right ? `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: people are too fast to downvote and say about SO rules. but most of the popular questions tends towards common questions as i asked. In the question itself i asked the information about removal declarations which i haven't found any where on net.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to find out what functions are deprecated in various versions, the best source for this information is the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php).

Check the "Migrating from .." pages under appendices for details on which functions are deprecated in each version.